# While working with Android, if I want to insert into a database in mySql in localhost, where do I place my insert.php file?

Tags: php, android, localhost, http-post

The following line of code is used to access the php file while if u need to insert the values into a MySql database : "HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("htt://10.0.2.2/insert.php");" . Can anyone tell where should I save this php file ? Should I store it in "C:\xampp\htdocs"  (I'm using XAMPP server as my localhost ). ?

Comment: if your document root is "C:\xampp\htdocs", yes, this is the place

Comment: `While working with Android, if I want to insert into a database in mySql in localhost, where do I place my insert.php file?`.  Very wrong subject. Your problem has nothing to do with Android. Nor with a database. Nor with localhost. Nor with http-post. Better would have been: `For my webserver on my PC, in which folder on  do i place php scripts?`.

Comment: Ya Adrian Sir, I got the app running. I was actually creating a sample application in which their is a text field and a button. If you click on that button, the data in the EditText should be inserted into the database. So, now , when I'm working with my local database, the app is running good. But when i'm trying to connect it to the same php file which is on the web server, the data is not getting inserted there even if I'm getting the Toast saying that "Data Has Been Inserted".